# Printing the function that prints True, but also prints false

Tags: python

My problem with this code is that I want it to print Current Offence: Player, but also Current Defender: Cpu

Here is the code:

```
import random

Player = False
Cpu = False
user = input("Please enter [H]eads or [T]ails: ")

def flip_coin(Player, Cpu, user):
    # Flips coin to determine who has the ball first. 
    COIN = ["H", "T"]
    coin = random.choice(COIN)
    print("Coin is on: " + str(coin))
    
    if coin == user:
        Player = True
        return "Player"
    else:
        Cpu = True
        return "Cpu"

print("Current Offence: " + str(flip_coin(Player, Cpu, user)))
print("Current Deffence: " + str(flip_coin(Player, Cpu, user)))
```

Output:

```
Please enter [H]eads or [T]ails: H
Coin is on: H
Current Offence: Player
Coin is on: H
Current Deffence: Player
```

Expected Output:

```
Please enter [H]eads or [T]ails: H
Coin is on: H
Current Offence: Player
Current Deffence: Cpu
```

How can I make it to where Current Offence is on Player, but also Current Deffence is on Cpu without it being on Player?

Comment: There's only one value of `user` shared by both calls to `flip_coin`. You probably want to move `user = input(...)` *inside* the function.

Comment: Look up duck testing or rubber duck debugging. How many times do you want to flip the coin here?

Comment: Well, yes, you flipped the coin twice, and used each result. If you want to flip the coin only once, then you need to use a *separate piece of logic* to determine the other result. So, try to think first: what is the *rule that tells you* who the defense is, given that you know who the offense is? How would you write code to implement that rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one bool (or int) to hold all the information:

```
import random

players = ["Cpu", "Player"]

def flip_coin(coin):
    return random.choice("HT") == coin

user = input("Please enter [H]eads or [T]ails: ")        
player = flip_coin(user)
print(f"Current Offence: {players[player]}")     # Note: True == 1
print(f"Current Defence: {players[not player]}") # and: False == 0
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the answer I was about to post. The only real difference was that I put everything (except players) in `flip`.